# Chain To Then Function While Encapsulating One in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, sweetalert2

I'm a new ecmaScript6-student. 
I need to chain to "then" promises while encapsulating a library function.
*Swal is sweetAlert2 function to ask questions and get response from user, yes/no.*

Here is what I'm trying to do;

```
class MyLib {

    constructor() {
    }

    static askQuestion(title, message){
        Swal.fire({
            title: title,
            text: message,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            return result;
        })
    }
}
```

Then call this function like;

```
MyLib.askQuestion("Are you sure?", "Are you sure you want to delete this ?").then(alert(result));
```

But ofcourse; on runtime console gives me ".askQuestion(...) is undefined" because of the alert(**result**).

How do I chain two then function in es6 ?

Comment: You forgot the `return` statement in `askQuestion`. (and the `then()` callback is pointless as it just returns the result of resolving the promise unmodified)

Comment: Remove the ```then()``` from askQuestion and return the ```Swal.fire``` directly.

Comment: Thank you very much @SajeebAhamed. It worked.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your promise:

```
class MyLib {

    constructor() {
    }

    static askQuestion(title, message){
        return Swal.fire({
            title: title,
            text: message,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        });
    }
}
```

And, as others have said, your `.then(result => {return result;})` was pointless so it can be removed.

Then, when you use it, you have to pass a functon **reference** to `.then()` so change this:

```
MyLib.askQuestion("Are you sure?", "Are you sure ...").then(alert(result));
```

to this:

```
MyLib.askQuestion("Are you sure?", "Are you sure ...").then((result) => alert(result));
```

or this:

```
MyLib.askQuestion("Are you sure?", "Are you sure ...").then(alert);
```

And, if `Swal.fire()` can ever reject it's promise, you need a `.catch()` too.

Comment: @lost_in_library - Make sure you see the additional part I just added to the end of the answer.